# generate new address for blockchain wallet

Tags: php, blockchain

I am using blockchain API to generate a new address for every wallet.
Here is the code:

```php
<?php
$guid = "7c74bb77-4e25-4eea-a9d3-df1cf6a9d218";
$main_password = "******";
$label = "firsttym";
$json_url = "http://localhost:3000/merchant/$guid/new_address?
password = $main_password & label = $label";

$json_data = file_get_contents($json_url);

$json_feed = json_decode($json_data ,true);

$message = $json_feed->message;
$txid = $json_feed->tx_hash;
?>
```

It always returns this warning:

> Warning: file_get_contents(localhost:3000/merchant/7c74bb77-4e25-4eea‌​-a9d3-df1cf6a9d218/…‌​) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream:
>   A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
>
> in C:\wamp\www\block\first.php on line 8
>
> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\wamp\www\block\first.php on line 8

Comment: it always returns that:Warning: file_get_contents(http://localhost:3000/merchant/7c74bb77-4e25-4eea-a9d3-df1cf6a9d218/new_address?password=hasnisidra17&label=firsttym) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. in C:\wamp\www\block\first.php on line 8

Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\wamp\www\block\first.php on line 8

Comment: Having submitted an edit to the question, I can see there are a couple of syntax errors in the question... After my edit is approved (you can do that if you wish), please ensure these errors are not in your actual code and then edit this answer to fix them.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try it like this: I have been using this to get new addresses

> Don't forget to start the block chain service before you make the request
>
> blockchain-wallet-service start --port 3000

```
$url = "http://localhost:3000/merchant/$guid/new_address?password=$password&label=$label";
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);



   $data = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), TRUE);

   return $data;
```

Comment: geeting error about Call to undefined function curl_init()

Comment: install curl on your system... you can check it on phpinfo

Comment: getting no output on the localhost

Comment: it gives blank page

Comment: try to browse the url directly and see if it returns an address

Comment: i tried it but it always give me error .will you specify me the address which i can put in the browser

Comment: have you started the service ?

Comment: have you started it like this: blockchain-wallet-service start --port 3000 ??

Comment: no, how can i start like as you said..??? blockchain-wallet-service start --port 3000

Comment: you should start it like that otherwise you won't get a result... you can start it from the terminal...

Comment: how can i setup according to your recommendations?//

Comment: are you using windows or linux?